# How do I create random Boolean array with at least one 1 in each row in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, random, boolean

I am trying to create roandom boolean arrays in Matlab with atleast one 1 in each row.

Comment: Have you tried something yet ?

Comment: how many ones do you need at each row? 50%? 25% only one?

Comment: Yes. A = round(rand(m,n)) % for a m*n matrix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can  use randi to generate random integers?

```
A = randi([0 1], 50, 10);
```

Generate a 50-by-10 array of integer values drawn uniformly from 0 or 1 and
you can convert matrix to dataset array by

```
   ds = mat2dataset(A);
```

to convert a binary row to a number - as in the previous answers:

```
bin2dec(num2str(A(n,:)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want a random logical (boolean) matrix of size `m`-by-`n` with roughly `p=0.25` entries set to `true` at each row *but not less than one*, then you can simply:

```
P = rand(m,n); %// generate random numbers in [0,1]
th = min( max(P,[],2), 1-p ); %// set threshold
B = bsxfun( @ge, P, th ); %// threshold the probability matrix to get random boolean entries
```

Note that the threshold is determined by the amount of `true` values you want per row, but it is also truncated to the `max` value of each row, ensuring that at least one element (at random) will be set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. Let

```
M = 5; %// number of columns
N = 4; %// number of rows
p = .5; %// initial probability of 1
```

You can generate the matrix with the given probability of ones, and then fill in a one at a random position in each row (possibly overwriting a zero) to make sure there's at least a one in each row:

```
result = rand(M,N)<p; %// generate matrix
result(bsxfun(@plus, floor(N*rand(1,M))*M, 1:M)) = 1; %// at least a one per row
```